# Animation little jump with jquery

Tags: jquery

My question is simple, I want to make a little animattion with jquery, it's a little jump, I have a icon at the top, and paragraph on the bottom, and the icon must go up and down, without the paragraph movement.
I think it's using margin bottom +20% to up and clear it to down, but how i make the paragraph static.
Here is a snippet to show it better.

```js
$( "span" ).animate({
    marginBottom: "5%",
  }, 1500 );
```

```css
div {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
span {
    float : right;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
p {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep your logo in a div and then animate marginTop

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nq418d2x/) , you can alter hight and width of div make it float right.

HTML:

```
<div id="logo"><span><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span></div>
```

Comment: With your solution I can move first down and before up, but it's the contrary order, first up then down, I can't make this :S

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `span` `position:relative` , calling `.animate()` with `top:-20` argument

```js
$( "span" ).animate({
    // set `top` animation in `px` units here,
    // e.g.; `-20`
    top: "-20", 
  }, 1500 );
```

```css
div {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
span {
    position: relative;
    float : right;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
p {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would prefer dont use positions, so the first solution in my case it's the best option, anyway thanks for the help !